# Spaces of maps to/from projective spaces as invariants of varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mu_n(X) = [\mathbb{P}^n, X]_{/PGL_{n+1}}$ be the set of equivalence classes of (regular/rational) maps to an algebraic variety $X$ from the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ modulo automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Similarly define $\mu^n(X) = [X, \mathbb{P}^n]_{/PGL_{n+1}}$ for maps going the other way.

I imagine these sets can be realized as stacks by taking $PGL_{n+1}$-quotients of Hom-stacks (for the regular maps case at least.)

What do we know about these spaces and about their inter-relationships as $n$ varies, for maps, correspondences and fibrations of varieties?

The motivation for thinking about these is their potential as invariants, in analogy with homotopy groups. How well would they do that score?

Comment: The automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}^n$ is $PGL_{n+1}$, not $PGL_n$.